# What does "(?u)" do in a regex?

Tags: python, regex

I looked into how tokenization is implemented in scikit-learn and found this regex ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c957249/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1215)):

```
token_pattern = r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b"
```

The regex is pretty straightforward but I have never seen the `(?u)` part before. Can someone explain me what this part is doing?

Comment: It's equivalent to `re.U` flag

Comment: And looks rather Python specific.

Comment: @sln: Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It switches on the [`re.U` (`re.UNICODE`) flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.U) for this expression.

From the [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> `(?iLmsux)`
>
> (One or more letters from the set `'i'`, `'L'`, `'m'`, `'s'`, `'u'`, `'x'`.) The group matches the empty string; the letters set the corresponding flags: `re.I` (ignore case), `re.L` (locale dependent), `re.M` (multi-line), `re.S` (dot matches all), `re.U` (Unicode dependent), and `re.X` (verbose), for the entire regular expression. (The flags are described in Module Contents.) This is useful if you wish to include the flags as part of the regular expression, instead of passing a flag argument to the `re.compile()` function.